# Proving the group of rotational symmetries of a Tetrahedron has no element of order 6

Tags: group-theory

How would one prove that the group of rotational symmetries of a Tetrahedron, $G$,  has no element of order 6?

I think that there is no element of order 6 and hence no cyclic subgroup of order 6, but cannot generalize this to proving there is no subgroup of order 6.

Answer (score 3):

$G$ is a subgroup of $S_4$, infact every element of $G$ is a permutation of the four vertices of the tetrahedron, but $S_4$ has no elements of order 6 and has no subgroups of order 6.

Comment: Note that you need to check that the action of the rotation group on the vertices is faithful.